# Why have consumer-level graphing calculators seemingly not developed in 20+ years?

Tags: numerics

Apologies if this is the wrong forum to post this question in - I truly don't know where else I would (if you do, please let me know!).

But essentially, I am not a mathematician, though I was reading up on the various technological advancements of calculating technology and had the following thought:

The TI-84Plus was released in 2004, I used it in High School - it cost me around $120.

If you go online and now and search for Graphing Calculators, the TI-84Plus is still one of the first and only results. It costs $150.

Other options seem to either have significantly less functions, or are designed near exclusively for high level academics and engineering workers, with price points around $1500.

So my question is, in an era of rapidly advancing technology and pocket sized computers, why have Graphing Calculators seemingly stood still? The “TI” series used to advance every couple of years before suddenly stopping at the TI-84, and in a year where a person can buy a basic smartphone or even full fledged Micro PC for around $100 - how and why has no company produced a graphing calculator with similar (or better) capacities but a lower price point than the 2004 TI-84Plus?

Is it the technology? Does Texas Instruments have some unique hold over the market where some foreign company couldn't sell essentially the same product for $30? Is this a purely economic issue?

Comment: I'll leave to the Community at large to weigh in on whether this is suitable for the site, but let me articulate why I see it as off-topic.  There is no nexus to an actual computational science problem.  It veers strongly towards economics and manufacturing issues, without making a connection to a specific problem that you would solve with said "graphing calculator."  I suspect the gist of an answer is embedded in your Question, that whatever functions might be provided by a handheld(?) calculator can be provided on a notebook or "netbook" computer (or even a smart phone).

Comment: @njuffa Yes, they use them, because schools allow them in exams. Basically the main killer feature of pocket calculators is *not* being able to connect to the internet, so that they are allowed in exams.

Comment: @njuffa And the habit is strong: I teach a 3rd-year course where a good 50% of the final written exam is coding algorithms on Matlab, and it boggles my mind that some students still bring a calculator and use it. Sometimes I feel like I completely failed teaching them how to use a computer for numerics.